# Нужна ли запятая перед "и" в предложении, приведенном далее?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

Уважаемые филологи. Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед "и"?

> Приближается весна и настало время снимать зимнюю одежду.

Comment: Если Вас устраивает один из ответов, пожалуйста, пометьте его как принятый (галочка слева

Answer (score 1):

Я не филолог, но постараюсь ответить.

Это сложносочинённое предложение с союзом *и*. По общему правилу простые предложения, входящие в состав сложносочинённого предложения, отделяются друг от друга запятыми.

Запятая перед союзом не ставится, если простые предложения в составе сложносочинённого предложения имеют общий элемент. Но такового нет в Вашем предложении, поэтому запятую нужно ставить:

**Приближается весна, и настало время снимать зимнюю одежду.**

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вы очень емко и понятно ответили. А то у меня школа так далеко, что я уже все забыла...

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае союз **и** соединяет две части сложносочиненного предложения. Каждое простое предложение имеет свою грамматическую основу (подлежащее и сказуемое).
Запятая перед союзом ставится.

**Приближается весна, и настало время снимать зимнюю одежду.**
*Весна приближалась, и день заметно прибавился...*
*Приближается лето, и перед родителями встает вопрос — куда отправить ребенка...*

Об особых случаях пунктуации можно прочитать здесь:
[Запятая при одиночном использовании союза «и» в предложении](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html?start=1)